# Calling a specific function alone in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

i have a piece of code like this.

```
// HTML file
<div class="box" ng-click="displayinfo()">
    click here to display info about this page.
    <div class="content" ng-click="displaytext()">
        Click here to display text.
    </div>
    click here to display info about this page.
</div>

// JS file
$scope.displayinfo = function()
{
    alert('info');
}
$scope.displaytext = function()
{
    alert('Text');
}
```

the thing is while clicking on 'click here to display text', it is calling both functions and displaying 'Text' and 'info'. but i dnt want to display 'info' here. i cannot change the html div structure.

how to do that?

Comment: Lookup the cancelBubble() javascript function

Comment: check the class from the element (div) you come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hidden in the docs, but if you look here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick

You can see that parameters it mentions an $event object. So your html will become:

```
<div class="box" ng-click="displayinfo($event)">
    click here to display info about this page.
    <div class="content" ng-click="displaytext($event)">
        Click here to display text.
    </div>
    click here to display info about this page.
</div>
```

and then your javascript will become:

```
$scope.displayinfo = function($event)
{
    $event.stopPropagation();
    alert('info');
}
$scope.displaytext = function($event)
{
    $event.stopPropagation();
    alert('Text');
}
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/rtCP3/32/

Comment: wow great. it really helped me to solve lot of pblms. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Instead calling functions there inline use jquery to solve this issue:

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    displayinfo();
});

$('.content').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); //<-------------------this will stop the bubbling
    displaytext();
});
```

demo code for `e.stopPropagation()`: http://jsfiddle.net/HpZMA/

```
var a = "text for info";
$('.box').click(function(){
    $(this).append(a)
});

var b = "text for info";
$('.content').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); //<-------------------this will stop the bubbling
    $(this).append(b)
});
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular as well. I would suggest reading up on what they are accomplishing with ng-click and the rest of angular in the docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick

Comment: @MathewBerg Never worked on angular js but will see for sure, seems interesting.

Answer (score 1):

For native javascript solution you need to pass `event` as argument to your 2 methods in order to prevent the event from propagating

```
<div class="box" onclick="displayinfo(event)">
```

Then change js to:

```
var displayinfo = function(event) {
    event.cancelBubble = true
    alert('info')
}

var displaytext = function(event) {
    event.cancelBubble = true
    alert('text')
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/MvgTd/

Comment: yes this will work only if use var displayinfo=function. how to make it work for $scope.displayinfo=function(). both are different. when i tried printing events it is displaying undefined.

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular. Removing the logic from inline defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

whatever you are getting.stopPropagation();
in your case

```
$event.stopPropagation();
```